# Azure DevOps Deployment to Azure SQL Managed Database

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-managed-instance

Is there a way to deploy SQL Database project to Azure SQL Managed Database from Azure DevOps ? Are there ports to open on Azure Network Security Group ?

Thank you

Bertrand

Answer (score 2):

No, not using Azure DevOps hosted agent. That is because a managed instance does not have a public ip address an DevOps can not find your server. If you want to use DevOps you must host your own agent on a separate VM and open up all the internal/external routing you need.

Answer (score 0):

the 'Azure SQL Database Deployment' task in the release pipeline should work for you. With a service connection (Service Principal in Azure) with the correct permissions on the subscription or resource group you can write to the resources, no need to open specific ports in NSGs

Comment: There is no public network connectivity to managed instances, only internal VNET connectivity, so there is no way for a cloud solution such as DevOps to connect to a private service such as SQL Managed Instance. It can certainly perform things at the "console" level but this is only things like scaling up and down - not actually connecting to a database and performing data operations

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible on MI and Azure DevOps.

Not sure what the NSG settings are if you have restricted access via a NSG.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).